# CPP how to escape a quotation mark

Tags: c-preprocessor, quotes

I'm in the process of making code from 1991 work on Ubuntu 19.

I've got this file I need to run through CPP where I am forced to use the -traditional option.

```
#define ITEM_WEAPON 5
#define ITEM_FIREWEAPON 6
Trade types = "+ITEM_WEAPON+ITEM_FIREWEAPON+"
```

I want the line to become

```
Trade types = "+5+6+"
```

This worked just fine in 1991-1997 ;-) It seems cpp for obvious reasons no longer parse between quotation marks.

I've tried to escape the quotes using the backslash character e.g.

```
Trade types = \""+ITEM_WEAPON+ITEM_FIREWEAPON+\""
```

But still haven't found a good solution.

For clarity this is not a C program, instead we simply used cpp to expand various macros into a structured text file which was later run through a parser.

The closest I have come (with -traditional flag) to something that almost works is this:

```
#define WI 1
#define WJ 2

#define T(a,b) Trade types = "+a+b+"
T(1,2)
T(WI,WJ)
```

Which outputs:

```
Trade types = "+1+2+"
Trade types = "+WI+WJ+"
```

So the pre-processor does substitute the arguments between the quotes but does not expand the parametized macro.

Comment: "good" solution would be to get rid of the macros. Why arent they eg `const std::string`s? What is `Trade` ? Does it expect a char array or a `string`?

Comment: the preprocessor never expanded macros inside quoted strings.  could there have been a separate pre-compilation step using a custom tool?

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/R5sLKvGhcnL9Jgyj

Comment: Concerning _This worked just fine in 1991-1997._: I doubt that any C compiler expanded macros inside of string literals. What compiler did you use? (in 1991-1997)

Comment: I just checked in "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie. It is explicitely mentioned that substitutions cannot occur inside "..." (I checked 1983 version).

Comment: Pre-standard C++ compilers not necessarily conformed to C standard. I wouldn't be surprised if Turbo or some other compiler did that.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I considered pre-ANSI C compilers as well in my speculations. I also was surprised that Bjarne Stroustrup started 1979 with C++ where he (on the other hand) started with C-Front (which compiled C++ into C). However, concerning _I'm in the process of making code from 1991 work_: Maybe, it would be worth to re-implement the code instead of "make it work"... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define ITEM_WEAPON 5
#define ITEM_FIREWEAPON 6

#define STRINGIFY_HELPER(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY_HELPER(x)


int main()
{
    std::string types = "+" STRINGIFY(ITEM_WEAPON) "+" STRINGIFY(ITEM_FIREWEAPON) "+";
    std::cout << types << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/R5sLKvGhcnL9Jgyj

Answer (score 1):

With more macros you can do that:

```
#define ITEM_WEAPON 5
#define ITEM_FIREWEAPON 6

#define MAKESTRING2(s) #s
#define MAKESTRING(s) MAKESTRING2(s)

Trade types = "+" MAKESTRING(ITEM_WEAPON) "+" MAKESTRING(ITEM_FIREWEAPON) "+";
```

But I also would try avoiding macros:

```
#define ITEM_WEAPON 5
#define ITEM_FIREWEAPON 6

const std::string types = "+" + std::to_string(ITEM_WEAPON) +  "+" + std::to_string(ITEM_FIREWEAPON) + "+";
```

Or even better:

```
constexpr int ITEM_WEAPON = 5;
constexpr int ITEM_FIREWEAPON = 6;

const std::string types = "+" + std::to_string(ITEM_WEAPON) +  "+" + std::to_string(ITEM_FIREWEAPON) + "+";
```

Answer (score -1):

Running

cpp -traditional

on this file

```
#define WI 1
#define WJ 2

#define T(a) Trade types = \"+a+"
T(WI+WJ)
```

will produce the following output:

```
Trade types = \"+1+2+"
```

Which is the closest I could come to replicating the behavior of old times past :)

Given all the comments, which I agree on I think this will have to suffice.